# Помогите написать mysql запрос по n числу таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день! Прошу помощи! Есть несколько таблиц

```
CREATE TABLE qurum (
`q_id` INT NOT NULL,
`qurum` varchar NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (q_id),
) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE data (
`id` INT NOT NULL,
`qurum` varchar NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (qurum) REFERENCES qurum(q_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE i1 (
`i1_id` INT NOT NULL,
`data_id` tinyint NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (data_id) REFERENCES data(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE i2 (
`i2_id` INT NOT NULL,
`data_id` tinyint NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (data_id) REFERENCES data(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
INSERT INTO qurum (q_id,qurum) VALUES
(1,'var1'),
(2,'var2');
INSERT INTO data (id,qurum, date) VALUES
(1,'1','2017-04-25'),
(2,'1|2','2017-03-24'),
(3,'2','2017-07-25')
INSERT INTO i1 (i1_id,data_id) VALUES
(1,1),
(2,1);
INSERT INTO i2 (i2_id,data_id) VALUES
(1,2),
(2,3);
```

Они связаны так: qurum.q_id = data.qurum, data.id=i1.data_id, data.id=i2.data_id и т.д. Надо посчитать кол-во строк в i1, i2 и т.д. Помогите написать запрос чтобы получить результат вида:

```
q_id|qurum|I|II
```

I  - это первое полугодие
II - это второе полугодие

Comment: Покажите эти свои "несколько таблиц" в форме *CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO*

Comment: Я не очень понял зачем так показывать?

Comment: Да чтобы хоть что-то было понятно... не, мне параллельно, не у меня ж проблема.

Comment: @Akina я исправил.

Comment: `qurum.q_id = data.qurum` - целочисленное поле связано с текстовым? Как и зачем?

Comment: а 1|2 может быть целочисленным? если да то я поменяю

Comment: Ну в q_id у вас же не 1|2 ?? Ёпрст, я не посмотрел в данные, это поле необходимо нормализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если абстрагироваться от **ненужного**(не участвующего в обеспечении целостности данных) поля `data.qurum`, то можно объединить все таблицы `i1..in` в **общий источник данных** с помощью `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT t.q_id, q.qurum, 
SUM(MONTH(d.date)<=6) I, 
SUM(MONTH(d.date)>6) II
FROM (
  SELECT 1 q_id, i1.data_id FROM i1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 q_id, i2.data_id FROM i2
) t
INNER JOIN qurum q ON q.q_id = t.q_id
INNER JOIN `data` d ON d.id = t.data_id
GROUP BY t.q_id
```

*Хотя, я бы порекомендовал отказаться от идеи разделять эти данные по разным таблицам.*

---

Если получится запустить, вот [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a5015/1)

Результат:

```
q_id qurum I II
1    var1  2 0
2    var2  1 1
```

Comment: Поле data.qurum используется чекбоксами в форме и показывает какие чекбоксы выбраны. Таблиц около 30 может быть больше или меньше

Comment: Состояние каждого чекбокса должно быть представлено строкой в базе или её отсутствием( в таблице dataqurums, например)

Comment: i1, i2 это и есть qurum, в них есть data_id. Т.е. если qurum = 1 то идет запись в i1,  если qurum = 2 то идет запись в i2 и т.д.

Comment: Если бы в i1 была бы строка `(2,2)`, а не `(2,1)`, было бы понятно

Comment: таблицу data я собираюсь использовать для редактирования данных а qurum-ы уже для составления отчетов. Если юзер поменяет qurum-ы тогда запись из соответствующей таблицы удаляется и записывается в другой

Comment: Теперь мне надо посчитать кол-во строк в каждом i1 - i30 в соответствии с названием qurum-а и поделить на 1-ое или 2-ое полугодие

Comment: Я изменил ответ

Comment: a если не известно сколько именно баз?

Comment: Изменение структуры данных во время эксплуатации, а не проектирования - изначально порочная практика. Соберите все эти таблицы в одну!

Comment: так они все в одной таблице data. там они в виде 1|2|3.  а в  i1 - i30 они  int. Пока что стадия проектирования.

Comment: 1|2|3 - не нужны, а i1-i30 должны быть одной таблицей с доп.полем q_id

Comment: Спасибо за совет! щас все изменю. я новичок и приходится трудно)) напишу здесь что получилось побеспокою еще вас

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57758/discussion-between-jabbar-guliyev-and-vp-arth).